# Изменение размера двумерного вектора

Tags: c++, vector

Есть двумерный вектор `std::vector< std::vector < int> > vecInt1`.
Как задать и изменить кол-во элементов в строке и столбце во время исполнения программы? Т.е. к примеру сначала был вектор 10*6, потом стал 15*13 и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополняя ответ @diraria

Да, нужно использовать `vector::assign`, но при этом надо понимать, что размер каждого внутреннего вектора может быть своим.

Например, если мы сделаем так:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // пустой вектор
    vector<vector<int>> a;

    // вектор размера 7 x 5
    // то есть семь строчек, каждая строчка состоит из пяти элементов
    a.assign(7, vector<int>(5));

    // и отдельно, допустим, у третьей "строчки", мы сделаем длину 3
    a[2].assign(33);

    cout << "число строк: " << a.size() << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        cout << "число элементов в " << i << "-ой строчке: " << a[i].size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

То выведено нам будет:

```
число элементов в 0-ой строчке: 5
число элементов в 1-ой строчке: 5
число элементов в 2-ой строчке: 33
число элементов в 3-ой строчке: 5
число элементов в 4-ой строчке: 5
число элементов в 5-ой строчке: 5
число элементов в 6-ой строчке: 5
```

Соответственно, изменить размер "двумерного" вектора на N*M можно
с помощью строчки

```
a.assign(n, vector<int>(m));
```

При этом он будет заполнен нулями, это полностью затрет его.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать [`vector::assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign):

```
a.assign(число_строк, vector<int>(число_столбцов));
```

или с одновременным заполнением всех элементов новым значением:

```
a.assign(число_строк, vector<int>(число_столбцов, новое_значение));
```

---

Некоторые пояснения:

- у класса `vector` есть несколько [конструкторов](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), в том числе:

  - `vector(число_элементов)` — создаёт вектор указанного размера, элементы инициализируются конструктором по умолчанию
  - `vector(число_элементов, значение)` — создаёт вектор указанного размера и заполняет его копиями переданного значения
- также имеется метод `vector::assign`, которые принимает новое число элементов и значение, которыми новые элементы будут заполнены

---

Ну и ещё небольшой пример на [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kmksxW):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // пустой вектор
    vector<vector<int>> a;

    // вектор размера 7 x 5
    // то есть семь строчек, каждая строчка состоит из пяти элементов
    a.assign(7, vector<int>(5));

    cout << "число строк: " << a.size() << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        cout << "число элементов в " << i << "-ой строчке: " << a[i].size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: или просто `vector::resize`

Comment: @AndrioSkur, `resize` всё-таки в общем случае [не подходит](https://ideone.com/X95sL0)